# Sort column by value other than cell content

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, datatables

I'm using jQuery DataTables and I have one column that looks like shown below:

```
<td><span class="badge"> 123 </span>  <span> customer name </span></td>
```

i.e, I put first some number (ID), then the actual name which I want to sort by.

How can I tell jQuery DataTables to sort correctly by customer name?

Comment: Why don't you format like: "customer name 123", i don't think there's an easy way to do it the way you want

Comment: I did that before, but it just looked bad (numbers need to be aligned). Sorting did work when I switch the order of the elements inside the td. And anyway, I prefer the number before the name..

Comment: Ok, if you need that ... I think you can start from: https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/ , https://datatables.net/development/sorting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `data-order` attribute on `td` element as shown in [this example](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/html5-data-attributes.html).

```
<td data-order="customer name">
   <span class="badge"> 123 </span>  
   <span> customer name </span>
</td>
```

Comment: This is what I looked for. Now I try to do the same with JSON ajax data (for a different table). For my DOM table it does work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with jQuery.

```
<table id="example" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>12</td>
            <td data-search>Paul</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>13</td>
            <td data-search>Nickson</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
 </table>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
         $('#example').DataTable();
     } );
</script>
```

You have to add jquery.dataTables.min.js after including the jquery. You can find more about this [here](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/html5-data-attributes.html)